# Use of the aspirate after the indefinite article

Tags: pronunciation

How do you use the aspirated "h" after the indefinite article. Do you say "a historic occasion" (forcing the aspirate) or "an istoric occasion" (no aspirate)?The BBC tend to say "an historic occasion" (forcing the aspirate).

Answer (score 4):

In most dialects of American English, it is normal to say "a historic occasion", with the "h" pronounced.  This is considered normal, not forced.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this doesn't only apply to American English. I'd argue that `an historic` is always incorrect.

Comment: I speak American English, and I ***only*** pronounce the 'h' in 'historic' at the beginning of phrases and after vowels (including 'a'). If you're implying that people always pronounce the 'h' in 'historic' in American English, this is just plain wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor -- The original poster specifically asked about "h"es after indefinite articles (like "a" and "an").  In typical American English, "h"es are pronounces after some consonants, and omitted after others.  A descriptive set of rules would probably have a lot of exceptions.

Comment: @Jasper: as far as I'm concerned, 'r' is the only consonant I pronounce an 'h' in an unstressed syllable after. But 'h's in stressed syllables are always pronounced.

Comment: @ Rob -  In the antediluvian days of my youth, 'a historic' was considered rather infra dig. It is undoubtedly a minority usage these days, but please don't suggest that my friends and I have been speaking incorrect English for nearly seventy years.

Answer (score 3):

In his Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, (3rd edition, 2008) Wells notes that only 6% of speakers of British English pronounce 'historic' without 'h'. These people will use 'an'. He notes the pronunciation of 'hotel' with and without the /h/, but gives no figures.

When the /h/ is pronounced, the use of 'an' is rare. People who pronounce the /h/ after 'an' in 'history' and 'hotel' are, in my opinion, hyper-correcting.  They believe that the written 'h' should be pronounced, but have seen it in writing following 'an'

Comment: Many thanks for all your inputs. As a Derbyshire schoolboy (1950s) we were taught "let's find an 'otel" is acceptable because "hotel" has French roots. Hearing BBC announcers saying "An historic occasion" seems so pretentious.

Comment: Just because you pronounce *"historic"* with an 'h', it doesn't mean you pronounce *"an historic"* with an 'h'. I drop the 'h' in *"historic"* (and all words starting with an 'h' in an unstressed syllable) after most consonants, which means that *"an istoric"* would be just as reasonable an alternative as *"a historic"* for me.